# Element UI - Change text of loading

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `element-ui` and the `Loading` service.

I would like to be able to dynamically change the text when loading

#### Expected result

The text should be directly changed to `yyyy`

#### Actual result

The text is `load` and stays `load`

#### Question

How can I dynamically change the loading text after 1sec

https://jsfiddle.net/zxjbxg7x/

```
var Main = {
data() {
  return {
    text: 'load'
  }
},
methods: {
  openFullScreen2() {
    const loading = this.$loading({
      lock: true,
      text: this.text,
      spinner: 'el-icon-loading',
      background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
    });
    this.text = 'yyy';
    setTimeout(() => {
      loading.close();
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        text: 'load'
      }
    },
    computed : {
      loading () {
        return this.$loading({
          lock: true,
          text: this.text,
          spinner: 'el-icon-loading',
          background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        });
      }
    },
    methods: {
      openFullScreen2() {
        this.loading.text = 'yyy';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.loading.close();
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Could you please provide me an example where the text would be `initial text` then after 3 seconds it changes to something else then again changes then close